# INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS doesn't work when two columns have same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query that work perfectly to insert values when they doesn't exists on table:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (code, type, user_id)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 11, 2, 1) as tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE code = 11 AND type = 2 AND user_id = 1) LIMIT 1;
```

But when I have the same value for two columns it cause a `duplicate column (#1060)` error.

This is the query that cause the error:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (code, type, user_id)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 11, 1, 1) as tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE code = 11 AND type = 1 AND user_id = 1) LIMIT 1;
```

I tried some variations of that code but I can't get it working.

The problem is this line:

```
...
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 11, 1, 1) as tmp
...
```

I know that the error makes sense. But I need a way to avoid it.

You can run the above query to see the error.

Any ideas about how can we solve this?

If you know a different way to insert values when they doesn't exists, I'll appreciate it too.

Comment: Please add table definition.

Comment: Are there indexes on your table which is causing the error.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai No indexes...

Comment: The full error is ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name '1' and that's true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full error is ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name '1'  and that is true

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM (SELECT 11, 1, 1) as tmp;
ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name '1'
```

The problem then is that in the sub query the column name is acquired from the value in the absence of an alias.
so either provide an alias

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 11 c1, 1 c2, 1 c3) as tmp
```

or just select

```
SELECT 11, 1, 1
```

I'm not clear why you would want tmp?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In that scope we can't select two columns (values, in that case) with the same name because I have a `SELECT * FROM` before. If I run only `SELECT 11, 1, 1` it has no problem.

Comment: What I need is a way to not insert duplicated values

Comment: There are no duplicates in your sample inserts - unless you deem that if any single element already exists is a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks P.Salmon, the alias worked!! About `tmp`, I need to put an alias to avoid this error: `Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias`.